# Exercise 11, Section 3.4 from Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear algebra*

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $W$ be the space of all $n\times 1$ column matrices over a field $F.$ Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $F,$ and let $\scr B$ be an ordered basis for $V.$ For each $\alpha$ in $V,$ define $U\alpha = [\alpha]_{\scr B}$ (the coordinate matrix). If $T$ is a linear operator on $V,$ then $UTU^{-1}$ is a linear operator on $W.$ Accordingly, $UTU^{-1}$ is left multiplication by some $n\times n$ matrix $A.$ **What is $A$?**

*My attempt:* One can see that $U$ is an isomorphism of $V$ onto $W.$ Now consider the standard basis vectors of $W,\{\epsilon_i\}_{i=1}^n.$ To find $A,$ I just need to know the action of $UTU^{-1}$ on these vectors.

Let $\mathscr{B} = \{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^n.$ Observe that $U^{-1}(\epsilon_i)=\alpha_i.$ Further let $T(\alpha_i)=\beta_i=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{ij}\alpha_j=C_i^TB.$

where $C_i=\begin{bmatrix}c_{i1}\\\vdots \\c_{in}\end{bmatrix},c_{ij}\in F$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\vdots \\\alpha_n\end{bmatrix}.$

Now, $U(\beta_i)=[\beta_i]_{\scr B}=C_i$. Thus $A$ is the matrix with $j$th column $C_j$.

**Is my argument valid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. It can be made more illuminating, however.

The $i$th column of $A$ is $$A_i = UTU^{-1}(\epsilon_i) = UT(\alpha_i) = [T\alpha_i]_{\mathscr{B}} = ([T]_\mathscr{B})_i.$$

That is, $$A = [T]_\mathscr{B}.$$